# SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've run into an issue when my production database has been restored to a dev environment. In that DB, I have a stored procedure that is setting `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`. I'm not sure why this is being done (I didn't write it). The execution is working fine in production, however, I get the following error when I run in dev:

> INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

If I set it to `on`, the stored procedure runs fine in dev. I did find some information about rebuilding indexes that may cause this issue. I attempted a `rebuild all` on the table, but it didn't change the problem.  Any ideas?

The prod also has `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` and `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: Did you do what the message says? Verify that [SET options are correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)  for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations?

Comment: I would check the database setting compared to Production to make sure things match up within Database Properties -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Quoted Identifiers Enabled.

Comment: They are both set to false

Comment: It's not just a database-wide setting. It's important whether or not it was on when certain actions were performed. E.g. it must be `on` when you create an index on a computed column as documentation tells you. Did this setting have same value when respective actions in production and development were performed?

Comment: We have found the index that causes the issue.  It has a filter on it of Status = 'A'.  If we delete the filter, the issue goes away.  its not using double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

### Use of quoted_identifier

1. `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON`, then character enclosed within double quotes is treated as Identifier. So following command will successful.

```
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
    GO
    CREATE TABLE dbo.”Table”
    (id int,”Function” VARCHAR(20)) 
    GO
```

If we keep `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` then above statement gets failed.

### Objects created with quoted_identifier on in production environment

2. You may find objects which are created with your production environment by following query for which identifier is set `ON`

`SET QUTOED_IDENTIFIERS` setting as `ON`:

```
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME _
    (object_id) _
    FROM sys.sql_modules _
    WHERE uses_quoted_identifier = 1
```

Hence if you keep quoted_identifier status off, then your object doesn't get created in the development environment